# Reference request: Good lower division ODE textbook that combines with linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am taking an ODE course and the prof kept on making references to linear algebra. However my book (Dennis G Zill - Intro to Differential Equations) only contains algorithms to compute different solutions to ODE.

I cannot see the differential equation-linear algebra connection so I kept on coming here to ask stupid questions as to how the basis in linear algebra is similar to that of a basis for a function, so and so forth.

There are so many important theorems in linear algebra, but how it extends to function is totally not clear for me. If you know a textbook that somehow works the rank-nullity theorem for vectors and matrices into those of functions then I would be very happy!

Thanks

Comment: There's no escaping that a large part of ODE theory does not rely on linear algebra. (In fact, LA wasn't widely used as a tool to help solve ODEs until roughly the middle of the 20th Century.) You're not going to find any Intro to ODEs that uses linear algebra as a starting point. That being said, LA is a  useful tool for higher order ODEs and systems of ODEs. You might enjoy looking at Boyce-DiPrima *Elementary Differential Equations*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the textbook used to teach Math 54 at UC Berkeley, which is a course that covers both linear algebra and differential equations at an introductory level.

[http://www.amazon.com/Differential-Equations-University-California-Berkeley/dp/B009748CW8/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1423614645&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009748CW8)

It's kind of expensive, and I think it's actually just a simple combination of the relevant sections of individual books by Lay and Nagle.  I believe that Nagle wrote the diff. eqn. part and, if I recall collectively, it does make an effort to talk about differential equations in the language of linear algebra.  (I haven't looked at this book in over 5 years, so forgive me if my memory is failing me.)  Anyway, the point is that you could perhaps get the diff. eqn. book by Nagle instead of the full book for Math 54 if you're only interested in the differential equations portion.